# How to get stream to function?

Tags: raspicam, motion

I recently started a project to make a 24/7 stream on my ras pi.  I hooked up the camera module v2 any the system detects it. I updated and upgraded then installed motion.
I ran `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` and that worked. I entered `motion.conf` turned daemon on the `turnedstream_localhost off` and updated the file to the camera's specs. I turned on `start_motion_daemon` and started `motion` but every time I type in http://raspberrypi:8081/ or its ip address with the port I get "This site can’t be reached Raspberry Pi refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
I've tried multiple devices VLC media player on multiple browsers but nothing is working. any help?

Comment: What's the model of your RPi and which OS have you installed?

Comment: I have a model 8B+ and am using raspbian

Comment: You are in the future. We don't have any **RPi 8 B+**. :)  I recommend a clean installation of motion service and test it by their default configuration. Next, try to change the value of the config file. I've tested before and I didn't face a problem like yours. Additionary, upgrade the OS to the latest version which is Buster.